# Find invalid values from JsonReaderException in Json.Net

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm running the code below to purposely throw JsonReaderException. It correctly gives the exception message of "Could not convert string to boolean: aaa. Path 'Active', line 3, position 17."

Is there any way to get the value that has failed the validation directly from the JsonReaderException so I don't have to parse the exception message?

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': 'aaa',
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

try
{
  Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
  Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
}
catch (JsonReaderException exc)
{
  // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the offending value is not saved as a property in [`JsonReaderException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReaderException.htm).  The only possible location for this value would be the [`Exception.Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Exception_Data) dictionary, however Json.NET does not add anything here.

However, with some work you can leverage Json.NET's [serialization error event handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) functionality to directly access the bad value at the time the exception is thrown.  First, define the following helper method and [`ErrorEventArgs`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ErrorEventArgs.htm) subtype:

```
public class ErrorAndValueEventArgs : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs 
{
    public object ReaderValue { get; } = null;

    public ErrorAndValueEventArgs(object readerValue, object currentObject, ErrorContext errorContext) : base(currentObject, errorContext)
    {
        this.ReaderValue = readerValue;
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static TRootObject Deserialize<TRootObject>(string json, EventHandler<ErrorAndValueEventArgs> error, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
            serializer.Error += (o, e) => error(o, new ErrorAndValueEventArgs(jsonReader.Value, e.CurrentObject, e.ErrorContext));
            return serializer.Deserialize<TRootObject>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to access the value of [`JsonReader.Value`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Value.htm) at the time the exception was thrown:

```
object errorValue = null;
try
{
    Account account = JsonExtensions.Deserialize<Account>(json, (o, e) => errorValue = e.ReaderValue);
    Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
}
catch (JsonException exc)
{
    // Do Something
    Console.WriteLine("Value at time of {0} = {1}, Data.Count = {2}.", exc.GetType().Name, errorValue, exc.Data.Count);
    // Prints Value at time of JsonReaderException = aaa, Data.Count = 0.
}
```

Notes:

- Since you must manually create your own `JsonTextReader`, you will need to have access to the JSON string (or `Stream`) for this approach to work.  (This is true in the example shown in your question.)
- A similar technique for capturing additional error information is shown in  *[JsonSerializationException Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53130847/3744182)*.
- You might want to enhance `ErrorAndValueEventArgs` to also record [`JsonReader.TokenType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_TokenType.htm).  In cases where the reader is positioned at the beginning of a container (object or array) at the time an exception is thrown, `JsonReader.Value` will be null.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y7nubw).